# Wordpress plugin: composer class not found

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I am developing a Wordpress plugin, I have composer inside my plugin directory at root level. I have installed all of the packages that I'd like to use and then I have PHP `use` commands loading in each namespace at the top of my plugin file after auto loading the packages.

PHP error

```
[28-Jun-2017 10:09:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp' not found in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/plugin-name.php on line 44
```

Plugin file structure

```
/plugin-name
 '- vendor/
 '- .gitignore
 '- composer.json
 '- plugin-name.php
```

composer.json contents

```
{
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol": "^2.0",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "~2.3.4",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^4.13.0",
        "mailchimp/mailchimp": "^2.0",
        "drewm/mailchimp-api": "^2.4"
    }
}
```

plugin-name.php contents

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Plugin name
[...]
*/
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use TheIconic\Tracking\GoogleAnalytics\Analytics;
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
use Stripe\Stripe;
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: In `plugin-name.php`, I needed to change

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Because the current working directory is always the root of the Wordpress installation, not inside my plugin directory.

The reason I wasn't getting an error on the `require` line is because I had another similar `vendor` directory in the root of the installation.